# How to get SharePoint list items from specific view using c#?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, view

I have created the SharePoint list and a custom view. I need to get the list items from the specific custom view instead of all items view. How to do this using c# with caml query?

I have used below code

```
   SPUser user = site.CurrentUser;
   AudienceLoader audienceLoader = AudienceLoader.GetAudienceLoader();
   SPList upcomingEventsList = site.Lists["Upcoming Events"];

   SPView view = upcomingEventsList.Views["Calendar"];

   SPQuery upcomingEventsQuery = new SPQuery();
   upcomingEventsQuery.CalendarDate = DateTime.Now;
   upcomingEventsQuery.ExpandRecurrence = true;
   string date = XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Now, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Local);
   upcomingEventsQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='LinkTitle'/><FieldRef Name='ID'/><FieldRef Name='Location'/><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/><FieldRef Name='EndDate'/>";
   upcomingEventsQuery.Query = "<View><Query>"+view.Views+"<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + date + "</Value></Geq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True'/></Now></OrderBy></Query></View>";
   SPListItemCollection SPListItemCollection = upcomingEventsList.GetItems(upcomingEventsQuery);
   DataTable upcomingEventsDT = SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable();
```

This is not getting the calendar items properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try below code. It fetches all items from `My Tasks` view.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("https://sitecollectionurl"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {   
       SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Tasks"); //list name
       if(list!=null){
           SPView view = list.Views["My Tasks"];   //custom view name
           
           SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(view);
        
           // Get a collection of view field names.
           StringCollection viewFields = view.ViewFields.ToStringCollection();
        
           // Print data for each item in the view.
           foreach (SPListItem item in items)
           {
              // Print the value of each view field.
              foreach (string fieldName in viewFields)
              {
                 Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", fieldName, item[fieldName]);
              }
              Console.WriteLine();
           }
       }
    }
}
```

**Never include Query in CAML**

Try it as below:

```
SPUser user = site.CurrentUser;
AudienceLoader audienceLoader = AudienceLoader.GetAudienceLoader();
SPList upcomingEventsList = site.Lists["Upcoming Events"];

SPView view = upcomingEventsList.Views["Calendar"];

SPQuery upcomingEventsQuery = new SPQuery();
upcomingEventsQuery.CalendarDate = DateTime.Now;
upcomingEventsQuery.ExpandRecurrence = true;
string date = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(DateTime.Now); 
upcomingEventsQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='LinkTitle'/><FieldRef Name='ID'/><FieldRef Name='Location'/><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/><FieldRef Name='EndDate'/>";
upcomingEventsQuery.Query = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + date + "</Value></Geq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True'/></Now></OrderBy>";
upcomingEventsQuery.ViewFieldsOnly=true;
SPListItemCollection SPListItemCollection = upcomingEventsList.GetItems(upcomingEventsQuery);
DataTable upcomingEventsDT = SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable();
```

Comment: I have added the reference code

Comment: @GokulPgp Check updated answer :)

Comment: we are not used the line
 SPView view = upcomingEventsList.Views["Calendar"];

Comment: Can you check now ? Have added full code.

Comment: yes, i have checked but it still retrieves the items from default view.

Comment: @GokulPgp are you sure that your custom view name is `Calendar`? Double check your view name. I am not sure but there can be also a case where display and internal name of view are different, and code expects internal name.

Comment: @GokulPgp - can you check now ? I have also added another condition `upcomingEventsQuery.ViewFieldsOnly` which brings only the viewfields specified in the `upcomingEventsQuery.ViewFields`

Answer (score 5):

Get sharepoint list items by view name:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://siteURL"))
         {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
               // Get data from a list.
               string listUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/tasks"; // List URL
               SPList list = web.GetList(listUrl);
               SPView view = list.Views["My Tasks"]; // Get view by name
               SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(view);

               foreach (SPListItem item in items)
               {                  
                  Console.WriteLine("{0}", item["Title"]);

                  Console.WriteLine();
               }
            }
         }
```

Comment: This is retrieves all items from list. not based on view.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the c# Client Object Model code to retrieve items from a custom view.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Connect to your SharePoint site and load object of your custom view
    //
    ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sp2013sps/sites/test");
    List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestListName");
    context.Load(list);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    View view = list.Views.GetByTitle("Test View");

    context.Load(view);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    // Create a new CAML Query object and store the query from the custom view
    //
    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
    query.ViewXml = view.ViewQuery;

    // Based on the query load items
    //
    ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
    context.Load(items);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.Write(items.Count);
}
```